# java - How can I fix this "error: array required, but String found" error in my server class for my University directory?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here is an excerpt of the code.

```
 while(true) { 
     System.out.print("Enter New Command: ");
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     String myLine = scan.nextLine(); //finds out whether command is to add,find, or delete
     String[] splitInfo = myLine.split(" ");
     if (myLine[0].equals("find")) { //*****ERROR********
        d.find(myLine[1]); //*****ERROR HERE******
     }
```

I made note of which lines my errors are occurring at. 
What am I doing wrong and how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: I think you want to use `if (splitInfo[0].equals("find")) {` instead of `if (myLine[0].equals("find")) {`. Same applies in the line thereafter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myLine` is your String and `splitInfo` your array. You have to change

```
if (myLine[0].equals("find")) {
    d.find(myLine[1]);
 }
```

to

```
if (splitInfo[0].equals("find")) {
    d.find(splitInfo[1]);
 }
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you, I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `if (myLine[0].equals("find"))`.

This should be `if (splitInfo[0].equals("find"))`.

Note that `d.find(myLine[1]);` should also be changed to `d.find(splitInfo[1]);`.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it

```
while(true) { 
    System.out.print("Enter New Command: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myLine = scan.nextLine();
    String[] splitInfo = myLine.split(" "); //The array which has tokens of myline
    if (splitInfo[0].equals("find")) { //look for 'find' in splitInfo
    d.find(splitInfo[1]);
}
```